# How to process specific model prices in Django with Stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

So here's my code first and foremost. I'm new to Django and trying to create an ecommerce site. The way it works is that the admin creates products and users come on to the site and purchase them. The site uses Stripe to process payments.

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator
    from django.conf import settings
    import stripe
    import decimal

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    from .models import Product
    # Create your views here.
    class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
        model = Product
        paginate_by = 3
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): # new
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
            return context

    def charge(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=round(decimal.Decimal(request.POST['price'])),
                currency='usd',
                description='A Django charge',
                source=request.POST['stripeToken']
            )
        return render(request, 'store/charge.html')


product_list.html:

{% extends 'home/base_generic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load cool_paginate %}
{% block add %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'store/css/products.css'%}">
{% endblock %}
{% block title %} <title> Store </title> {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
{% for product in product_list %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="card" id="django-card" style="width: 300px; height: 350px;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image.url }}" height=150px width=150px>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        {{ product.description }} And only {{ product.price }}!
      </p>
      <form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="{{ key }}"
          data-description="A Django Charge"
          data-amount= "{{ product.price_in_cents }}"
          data-locale="auto">
        </script>
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ product.price_in_cents }}">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;"> {% cool_paginate page_obj=product %}</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, my question is, when the user selects a product to purchase, how do I tell the view to use that products price? The way I've been doing it is using a hidden html value field in the input. But this can't be secure. Thanks to all who take the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few grueling hours of work I solved it. I opted to keep the hidden field form but instead of using price I used it to return the product primary key. Which I used in the view to grab the price and make charges.

Comment: I have similar type of issue i think you can help me on this . Link to my question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041815/how-to-customize-stripe-amount-field-from-static-to-dynamic-in-django